# Mongodb: Sorting multiple nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I recently started using mongodb (version 4.0.15) and cant try to figure out how to solve the below issue. I have a collection of documents which contains number of nested arrays. The requirement is to get only the latest info (element) from those arrays using timestamp and using a condition. I tried aggregation framework using $unwind, $sort, $group but not able to quite figure that out completely.Any help is appreciated.

Consider this one document below (similarly i have hundred of thousands of documents)
Here i need to list the information from memberinfo (not all the info but only certain fields), select the products and address (only specific fields) which are valid and with the latest timestamp and if no array element has the valid flag set to true, then get the array element with the latest timestamp even though the valid flag is false.

```
  {
    _id: x,
    member:
    {
      MemberInfo:
      {
        firstname: fn1,
        lastname : ln1,
        DOB: somedate
        gender: M,
        height: xx,
        weight: xx
        ….
      },
      Memberproducts: {
         MemberProduct: [
         {
           ProductName: product1,
           EffectiveDt: 1/1/2018,
           EndDt: 6/30/2018,
           Valid : true,
           description: desc1,
           ….
           ….
         },
         {
           ProductName: product2,
           EffectiveDt: 1/1/2019,
           EndDt: 12/31/2019,
           valid : true,
           description: desc2,
           ….
           ….
         },
         {
           ProductName: product3,
           EffectiveDt: 1/1/2020,
           EndDt: 12/31/9999,
           valid: false,
           description: desc3,
           …
           …
         },
        ]
      },
      MemberAddresses:
      {
        MemberAddress: [
        {
          street: address1,
          city: city1
          EffectiveDt: 1/1/2018,
          EndDt: 12/31/2019
          valid: false
           …
        },
        {
          street: address2,
          city: city2
          EffectiveDt: 1/1/2020,
          EndDt: 12/31/9999
          valid: false
          …
        } 
       ]
      }
   }
  }
```

Here is the intended output:

```
{
    member:
    {
      MemberInfo:
      {
        firstname: fn1,
        lastname : ln1     
      },
      Memberproducts: {
         MemberProduct: [
         {
           ProductName: product2,
           EffectiveDt: 1/1/2019,
           EndDt: 12/31/2019,
           valid : true
         },
        ]
      },
      MemberAddresses:
      {
       MemberAddress: [
       {
         street: address2,
         city: city2,
         EffectiveDt: 1/1/2020
         valid: false
       }
      ]
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to calculate the most recent date and then use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to keep only the array element that has `EffectiveDt` equal to the most recent `EffectiveDt`. Note that if you have multiple elements with that satisfy the condition, you may want to use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to select only one element

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "member.MemberInfo.firstname": true, // select firstname
      "member.MemberInfo.lastname": true, // select lastname
      "member.MemberAddresses.MemberAddress": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            recentDate: { // set recentDate as most recent EffectiveDt
              $max: "$member.MemberAddresses.MemberAddress.EffectiveDt"
            }
          },
          in: {
            $filter: { // filter only the address with the most recent date
              input: "$member.MemberAddresses.MemberAddress",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.EffectiveDt", "$$recentDate"] }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "member.Memberproducts.MemberProduct.EffectiveDt": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            recentDate: {  // set recentDate as most recent EffectiveDt
              $max: "$member.Memberproducts.MemberProduct.EffectiveDt"
            }
          },
          in: {
            $filter: { // filter only the product with the most recent date
              input: "$member.Memberproducts.MemberProduct",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.EffectiveDt", "$$recentDate"] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm to retrieve the array element with the latest timestamp. However, the requirement here is to get the array element for which valid flag is set to true and then to get the latest timestamp within those records. But if no array element has valid flag been set to true, then i need to get the element with the latest timestamp irrespective of valid flag.

Comment: I just realised, is your timestamp stored like this `12/31/2019` or is it of a `Date` type? of it's a string formatted just like that it will be more difficult to determine the most recent date.

Comment: it is of ISODate.

Comment: @AT are you able to post sample data that has data types that matches your real data? If you can provide such data, we can just copy it and test out queries. I think you could use $reduce to achieve what you want, but as you have somewhat complex logic, I think it would be much easier to manage this at your application layer